# Lambda function to stop RDS instance using tag filters

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-rds, boto3

I am trying to stop RDS instance using AWS Lambda function written in Python 2.7. However I cannot get the instances using the tag filters.

```
import boto3
import logging
rds = boto3.client('rds')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    filters = [{
            'Name': 'tag:Application',
            'Values': ['appname']
        },
        {
            'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
            'Values': ['running']
        }
    ]

    instances = rds.get_all_dbinstances.filter(Filters=filters)
    instances.status
```

Get all instances with the specified tags

This is the error I get:

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      18,
      "lambda_handler",
      "instances = rds.get_all_dbinstances(Filters=filters)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      553,
      "__getattr__",
      "self.__class__.__name__, item)"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "errorMessage": "'RDS' object has no attribute 'get_all_dbinstances'"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the function you are looking for is [describe_db_instances](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_instances). There is no function named `get_all_dbinstances`. Please refer to the documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to get all RDS instances and their status?